# use HP Procurve switch 5400zl as router between 2 networks

Tags: hp, hp-procurve, networking

I have a this network to explain :

```
---------------------                               -----------------------------

| HP Procurve Switch |  (A25) <----------> (Fa0/0) | Cisco Router As VPN-Router  |

---------------------                              ------------------------------

 Network : 192.168.1.0/24                             VPN Network : 10.0.0.0/8

IP A25 : 172.16.1.2

IP Fa0/0 : 172.16.1.1
```

I need to configure the HP switch as router to enable comminication between the 192.168.1.0 Network and the 10.0.0.0/8 VPN other side Network

Please can someone tell me the commands and the procedure to do this.

Comment: Can you post the full configuration?

Comment: We're not big fans of new users who come here, show little effort themselves and ask "Please do my job for me" - read what this site is, and isn't, for before posting again.

Answer (score 3):

Sure...

- set an IP on each VLAN interface on the HP ProCurve
- Enable routing with the "ip routing" command.

Make sure the there are routes using the switch VLAN interface IPs as gateways or that the devices use the switch's IP as their gateways.